# Regex not working

Tags: regex

This regular expresion does not work when I enter 100 for some reason but 100.0 is ok.

```
^(?!0*(.0+)?$)(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Which program or class are you using to evaluate this regex?

Comment: What is it SUPPOSED to recognize?

Comment: I presume the OP wants to get any positive number except something representing a zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your negative lookahead which causes the problem:

```
0*(.0+)?$
```

The dot in here means *any* character - you want to escape it:

```
^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$
```

Or even simpler with a positive lookahead:

```
^(?=.*?[1-9])(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$
```

Comment: so, sorry, how would it look the final regex then? The same without that dot?